# The iOS back to application button not there for all apps

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Swift based app that launches other apps using their URL Scheme. I am properly launching a few apps and understand how it all works. When I launch these app, the back to Launchpad (my app) button appears in the upper right but in 2 different third party apps, the app launches but there is no back to button.

Any idea what could cause this.

Comment: Try running it on a real iOS device and see if it shows up.